# How to terminate several processes in C with fork()?

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

I'm doing a project on Unix processes, using the languaje C. The project is to represent a tree of processes using, wait (the functions fork ()) exit ().

The output of my program should be me:

1. Father: PID1 - Hello
2. Children1: PID2 - Hello
3. GrandChildren1.1: PID3 - Hello and Goodbye
4. GrandChildren1.2: PID4 - Hello and Goodbye
5. Children1: PID2 - Goodbye
6. Children2: Pid6 - Hello
7. GrandChildren2.1: Pid7 - Hello and Goodbye
8. Children2: Pid6 - Goodbye
9. Father: PID1 - Goodbye

This output understand it.
I scheduled the following code to the beginning of the process, but not how do they finish processes:

```
main() {

    if(fork())
    {
        // 1
        printf("1. Father:Pid1 - Hello\n");
        if(fork())
        {
            // 2
            printf("2. Children1:Pid2 - Hello\n");
            if(fork())
            {
                // 4
                printf("3. GrandChildren1.1:Pid3 - Hello and GoodBye\n");
            }
            else{}

            wait(1);

            if (fork())
            {
                 printf("3. GrandChildren1.2:Pid4 - Hello and GoodBye\n");
            }
            else {}
        }
        else
        {
            printf("4. Children1:Pid2 - GoodBye\n");
        }
    }
    else{
        if(fork())
        {
            // 3}
            printf("6. Children2:Pid6 - Hello\n");
            if (fork())
            {
                printf("6. GrandChildren2.1:Pid7 - Hello and GoodBye\n");
            }
            else{}
    }
    else{}
    }

    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

This output understand it.
I scheduled the following code to the beginning of the process, but not how do they finish processes:

For example, do not know how to finish the PID2 and see that when you print 2 grandchildren, I have to.

How could it?

regards

Comment: Read about the `kill()` function and signal handling.

Comment: `wait(1);` And read the [wait man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) as that is not the right way to call it.

Comment: Hello iharob, I use not kill, only fork, wait, waitpid, exit, write, instructions.

Comment: You should explain that in your Question if it has to be without kill

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got your question, anyway form what I have understood you need to regulate the flow of execution. There are several ways:

> wait(),waitpid(),
>   kill(),
>   sigaction()

You can understand how they work looking on the man page of them.